# Exception training Resnet50: "The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I want to use `keras.applications.resnet50` to train a Resnet for a two class problem using the following setup:

```python
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.models import Model

resNet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None)
y = resNet.output
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(y)
model = Model(inputs=resNet.input, outputs=y)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 15
model.fit(train_tensors, train_targets, 
          validation_data=(valid_tensors, valid_targets),
          epochs=epochs, batch_size=10, callbacks=[checkpointer], verbose=1)
```

Running the code throws the error

```python
Exception: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined
```

So there must be something wrong with the input tensor to the output layer, which in my case is a one-hot encoded vector, i.e. a one-dimensional array of size 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get

> Exception: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined

because you have not set the input shape in your resnet network. Try:

```python
resNet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

Also since you are using binary_crossentropy with sigmoid activation in you output layer you should use only 1 neuron not 2, like this:

```python
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure about the second part of your answer, though. Doesn't one-hot encoding mean that you have as many output Neuron as classes, with each Neuron indicating the probability for the particular class?

Comment: if you want to use 2 neurons you should use softmax

y = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(y)

and categorical_crossentropy instead of binary_crossentropy

Answer (score 1):

Since you are applying no **pooling(avg or max)** to the output of your Resnet model, the output that it is providing is a 4-D tensor, being passed to your Dense layer. Its a good idea to apply pooling before the dense layer, which will extract either the **avg** or **max** of each feature from previous layer and will then pass onto the Dense layer. Another option is if you don;t want to apply pooling layer, then you can just apply a **Flatten()** layer to Resnet output, that would also convert the 4-D tensor to 2-D tensor, expected by your Dense layer.

Comment: I tried Flatten, but got another error. See the updated question.

Comment: Please try, applying pooling (avg or max), in the Resnet50 constructor, then you can remove the Flatten layer. If possible try to see what is the output shape of **resnet.output**, I think the problem with Flatten layer lies there